# How to prime selenium webdriver in conftest?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, pytest

I am trying to prime the selenium webdriver in a way that it can be instantiated in conftest.py while also defining which browser I am using via cli.

I am using code from this tutorial as a base but trying to made the setup function not hardcoded to use chrome but instead run the file via "--driver chrome" or "--driver firefox"
https://www.seleniumeasy.com/python/pytest-run-webdriver-tests-in-parallel

conftest.py

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def setup(request):
    print("Initiating selenium webdriver. . .")
    session = request.node
    for item in session.items:
        cls = item.getparent(pytest.Class)
        setattr(cls.obj, "driver", webdriver)
    webdriver.get("http://seleniumeasy.com/test")
    webdriver.maximize_window()

    yield webdriver
    webdriver.close()
```

test_file.py

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
def test_title(self):
         assert "Selenium Easy" in self.driver.title
```

I get the following error..

```
request = <SubRequest 'setup' for <Function test_title>>

    @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
    def setup(request):
        print("Initiating selenium webdriver. . .")
        session = request.node
        for item in session.items:
            cls = item.getparent(pytest.Class)
            setattr(cls.obj, "driver", webdriver)
>       webdriver.get("http://seleniumeasy.com/test")
E       AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'get'

parallel-tests\conftest.py:21: AttributeError
```

Comment: Why aren't you using function scoped fixture for driver initialization? Using session scoped fixture and attaching driver to all test items looks unnecessary complex.

Comment: @SilentGuy I am trying to run pytests in parallel that all access the same webpage. How would you recommend I structure this?

Comment: You can use pytest-xdist or pytest-parallel plugins and use function scoped driver fixture.